# windows mobile emulator

Tags: windows-mobile

I was developing a web application which was supposed to run on PC. But right now my boss want to me to change it a little bit so that it would be possible to access it on windows mobile.

My main concerns are:

- big amount of js, involved
- correct rendering of css and html

I can ask or get the phone running on windows mobile, and I will in the end run, but right now I am looking for an emulator for debugging.

I have went through [this link,](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=9263) but in my opinion this is an emulator for people who develop software application on windows mobile, so I have some doubts.

There is a possibility that the question is off-topic, but I can not find any better place for an advice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

using the Stand-alone-Device-Emulator with any of the Windows Mobile emulator images is the best you can do, if you do not have a device to test.

The question is, which devices you are targeting. If Windows Mobile 6.1.4, the link you mention is OK.

Additionally you should to load the Stand-alone-Device-Emulator from [here](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=5352). That enables you to start stop Windows Mobile Emulator images of different kinds.

[image]

The Internet Explorer Mobile inside the emulator behaves the same as on devices using the same OS. That is ensured by MS certification. OEMs just include the Internet Explorer as it is delivered by MS.

You may also need to load other emulator images like the Windows Mobile 6.5.3 (aka Windows Embedded Handheld 6.5.3) which is the latest available Windows Mobile OS. Windows Phone (7 or 8) is a totally different branch.

If oyu need an internet connection inside the emulator, you need to load and install [ActiveSync](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=15) (<=Windows XP) or Windows Mobile Device Center ([WMDC](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/search.aspx?q=windows%20mobile%20device%20center), >=Windows 7).
Do not interchange Windows Mobile Device Center with Windows Mobile Device Manager!

In ActiveSync or WMDC you can enable passthru of the ActiveSync/WMDC connection:
[image]

Choose "Allow Connections..." DMA option to allow the emulator to be 'cradled'.

If enabled, you can access the internet or the Computer's network within the emulator and so can connect to a web server running reachable from the Computer.
[image]

~josef